# jQuery: How to calculate and show sum of columns (partially working code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, nested-loops

I am new to JavaScript / jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a table with a row where some TDs within that row have a class "`calcSumColumn`".
For each of these I want to calculate and show the sum of the corresponding column.
All relevant **TDs that are to count contain a contenteditable div**.

**So far I have the following which shows something in the correct TDs in the sum row but it always shows 0 instead of the real sum of the column.**
Also, I wasn't really happy of having a nested loop here.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and also let me know if this can be achieved with only one loop ?

**My jQuery:**

```
var rowIndex,
    sumColumn = 0,
    current = $(e.target);
// ...
$(this).closest('table').find('td.calcSumColumn').each(function(){
    rowIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest('table').find('td').eq(rowIndex).each(function(){
        sumColumn += Number( $(this).find('div').text() );
    });
    $(this).text(sumColumn);
});
```

**Example TD to count:** (all TDs to count look the same)

```
<td class="calcInOut editable txtRight"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
```

**Example TD to show column sum:** (all TDs to show a column sum look the same)

```
<td class="calcSumColumn txtRight"></td>
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: can you include the html, or a demo similar to your html

Comment: `find('td').eq(rowIndex)` just returns a single `TD`, not all the `TDs` in that column.

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: That's not helpful. Please post the whole table, and explain which cells you want to get filled in with what values.

Comment: @Barmar: I cannot post the whole table since this is too big and it is created dynamically.

Comment: Just post enough for us to get the idea.

Comment: @Barmar: The TDs look exactly like the above so a row would just contain multiple of such TDs.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by the corresponding columns, so I need to see what sums should go where.

Comment: @Barmar: I am sorry, I will try to explain better: Example: The index of a TD to show a column sum is 5. Then I need to calculate and show the sum of all TDs with the index 5 resp. of the divs they contain - and this for all column where I have a TD with class "calcSumColumn".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add one more `each` so I can get each td of each tr. The second each I changed to be for `table tr` so each row will be iterated over. For each row I get the column(td) that has the same row index as the sum. If it has a div with `contenteditable="true"` then I will add the content to the sum for that column. Finally I reset the sum for each column.

```js
var rowIndex,sumColumn = 0;
    //current = $(e.target);
// ...
$('table').find('td.calcSumColumn').each(function(){
    rowIndex = $(this).index();
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $('td', this).eq(rowIndex).each(function(){
            if($('div[contenteditable="true"]', this).length==1)
                sumColumn += Number( $('div[contenteditable=true]', this).text() );
        });
    });
    $(this).text(sumColumn);
    sumColumn = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='sumTable' border=1>
    <tr>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">3</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">1</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">3</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">3</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">3</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">5</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">4</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable="true">8</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tt</td>
        <td class='calcSumColumn'></td>
        <td>tt</td>
        <td class='calcSumColumn'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks a lot ! Since I am new to JS would you mind adding one or two sentences to explain what is the main difference here to what I did ? Just wanna make sure I understand it right so that I can apply it to other things as well. :)

Comment: @keewee279 The main difference is that he's looping through all the rows, and then indexing a particular TD within that row. Your code just indexed the TD within a collection of all TDs.